# Error with the array in the shell script

Tags: bash, shell

In the following shell script, I use two arrays to store the numbers in p1.txt and p2.txt and then display them.

```
cat p1.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {party1[$i-1]=$i}}'
cat p2.txt | awk '{for(j=1;j<NF;j++) {party2[$j-1]=$j}}'
for ((k=1;k<10;k++))
do
    echo "${party1[$k]}"
    echo "${party2[$k]}"
done
```

However, when I run it with the default sh, it says Syntax error: Bad for loop variable;
when I run it with bash, no numbers can be displayed.
What's wrong with the script?

Comment: POSIX sh doens't support `for (( ... )); do`. Use bash.

Comment: I use bash but can see no numbers displayed..

Comment: For the array part there is already a brilliant answer covering that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=' ' read -r -a party1 <<< $(cat p1.txt)
IFS=' ' read -r -a party2 <<< $(cat p2.txt)

for ((k=1;k<10;k++))
do
    echo "${party1[$k]}"
    echo "${party2[$k]}"
done
```

Comment: Thx. I tried this but still no numbers can be displayed.

Comment: @haik, I updaded ans. maybe this can help you

Comment: for what it's worth, both the `read` and `mapfile` versions work on my computer running wsl.

Comment: @MustafaDOGRU It really works. I'm so grateful for your help.

Comment: @andlrc When I replace the start index k=1 with k=0, the whole array is displayed no matter what the terminating condition is.